# Multi Agent Sysytem - JADE - exchanging arrays as a message

Tags: eclipse, artificial-intelligence, agents-jade, agents, multi-agent

I'm developing a multi agent system via JADE in eclipse. I've managed to develop the code of exchanging messages between agents in different platforms, now I'm trying to make the agents send arrays to each other to be used in queries but couldn't get the hand of it. Any suggestions on how to pass it?

Comment: The Jade tag is for the HTML template language, I don't think you meant to use that

Comment: Anyways, assuming you can pass simple string messages, then you can use any multi-platform serialization format. JSON is just one example

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `setContentObject(Serializable s)` of the `ACLMessage` class. Just make sure that your objects within the array are [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).